# Weird .NET Memory Leak in ClickOnce app that can't repro as Desktop

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, devexpress, clickonce

In Visual Studio, are there any real difference between a "Release" build of an application, and a published version of the same application?

I have an ugly memory leak that's creeping up only in the published version installed via `ClickOnce`. The same leak does not occur in the "Release" build if I run the executable from the `project/bin` directory. I am very befuddled as to why this would occur because as far as I know, there should be no difference.

The application is a little involved so please excuse me for not providing more details. If it helps, the application uses `DevExpress XtraForm` objects and `Devart (CoreLab) MySQL` database objects.

**Edit:** I must be an idiot but I tried to profile the app with ANTS memory profiler and I can't seem to replicate the memory leak. When I run the actual application Mem Usage is clearly creeping up to uncomfortable levels in Windows Task Manager but memory usage in the ANTS profiler doesn't seem to increase.

Comment: Have you profiled the app to find what's leaking?

Comment: You need to verify that when you are testing you are performing the exact same actions as the people in production.  Also, as Martinho said, profile the app.

Comment: Additionally, is this just "excessive" memory usage? Or memory climbs steadily with usage?

Comment: Memory climbs steadily with usage until I get an out of memory exception. I am performing the exact same actions in both versions of the app. Thanks for the responses. I will profile the app and circle back.

Comment: are you sure you are using the profiler correctly? try creating a dummy memory leak example to verify it. That's what I did with .NET Memory Profiler. :)

Comment: Re: Kai Wang. Yup, I created an artificial memory leak by making a really large collection, and ANTS profiler correctly reflects that.

Comment: @stacked: I don't think that there's really enough to go on, here. Psychic debugging can only go so far. I assume that you're familiar with the usual memory gotcha's in .net (event subscriptions holding references and "leaked" references-- references maintained to large objects that will never be used again).

Comment: @Greg D: I agree. My apologies for the lack of information, I will try to continue profiling the app until I have better information. I was initially looking for some sort of straightforward explanation that someone might have out there, but I would certainly not exclude the possibility of the leak being entirely a result of my own idiocy.

Comment: This may not help solve your specific scenario, but I just listened to a great podcast on debugging complex problems...http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HanselminutesPodcast186NETDebugging101WithTessFerrandez.aspx